# How to chain reactor subscribers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactor

I have an existing interface chain I want to run as a [reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) instead of managing my own threads and queues

```
public interface UserLookupService {
    public User lookup(String id);
}
public interface UsersHandler {
    public void handle(List<User> users>);
}
```

```
UserLookupService userSvc = ...;
UsersHandler usersHandler = ...

// Works well to lookup users in parallel. 
Flux.just("userA", "userB", "userC")
    .parallel(2)
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .subscribe(str -> {
        userSvc.lookup(str);
    });
```

How can I chain that result so it invokes `UsersHandler` with batches of `User` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscribing to something triggers the chain, so you in general can't "chain" subscribers they are the last thing in the chain.

Think if it this way, you set up your reactive pipeline, and when you `subscribe`, you trigger the pipeline to start, and the chain will produce a result.

In a webserver, the `subscriber` is usually the calling client, and when the client `subscribes` he triggers the chain of events in the server that will publish data.

A `Flux` is kind of like a list of 1 to n `Mono`s. Each object in a `Mono/Flux` has a number of "states" so to speak. These are `Success`, `Error`, `Cancel`, `Next`, `Completed` and more.

When a `Mono/Flux` internally goes into a `Success` state it will emit the value in it. A `Mono` usually goes `Success` when something has resolved in the mono.

when you declare `Flux.just("userA", "userB", "userC")` you are basically asking the flux to resolve the input you are feeding into it. Placing a string is something that will resolve instantly so flux will go into a `Success` state and start emitting the strings as soon as something `Subscribes`. So all you have to do is then declare the chain you want to happen after someone `Subscribes`.

This can be done in several different ways, when you want to do something and change the value, like you want to from a `string` to a `user` we usually use `map`.

If we just want to do something with each object and not return anything we can use `doOnNext`.

```
Flux.just("userA", "userB", "userC")
            .parallel(2)
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .map(userString -> {
                return lookupService.lookup(userString);
            })
            .doOnNext(user -> {
                // if you want to do something on each user
                // will return void so if you want to log something
                // or handle each user
            }).subscribe();
```

Subscribing should be the last thing in the chain.